# asp.net core logged in IIS log files

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

When targeting the .NET framework and running the .NET core application in IIS, is it possible to take the output from the built-in provider and redirect / insert that into the IIS logs?

Something kind of like the [AppendToLog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.appendtolog(v=vs.110).aspx) method?